# Why can't I pass a directory as an argument to a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, directory

I have a simple bash script, simple.sh,  as follows:

```
#/usr/local/bin/bash
for i in $1
   do
       echo The current file is $i
   done
```

When I run it with the following argument:

```
./simple.sh /home/test/*
```

it would only print and list out the first file located in the directory.

However, if I change my simple.sh to:

```
#/usr/local/bin/bash
DIR=/home/test/*
for i in $DIR
   do
       echo The current file is $i
   done
```

it would correctly print out the files within the directory. Can someone help explain why the argument being passed is not showing the same result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you take "$1", it is the first file/directory, which is possible!
You should do it in this way:

```
for i in "$@"
do
  echo The current file is ${i}
done
```

If you execute it with:

```
./simple.sh *
```

They list you all files of the actual dictionary

"$1" is alphabetical the first file/directory of your current directory, and in the for loop, the value of "i" would be e.g. a1.sh and then they would go out of the for loop!
If you do:

```
DIR=/home/<s.th.>/*
```

you save the value of all files/directories in DIR!

Comment: This should be `"$@"` so it even works for files with spaces in their name.

Comment: And with `"$i"` the white space is retained in the message as well. It's all about details :-)

Comment: The last part of the explanation is slightly incorrect; pattern expansion does not occur in the right-hand side of a parameter assignment. When `$DIR` is expanded, the pattern is expanded as well if it is not quote (as in the original question). Verify with `echo "$DIR"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is as portable as it gets, has no useless forks to ls and runs with a minimum of CPU cycles wasted:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1
for i in *; do
   echo The current file is "$i"
done
```

Run as `./simple.sh /home/test`

Comment: "minimum of CPU cycles wasted" would probably be C rather than bash, tbh ;-)

Comment: Nope; not when the carbon-footprint, uh, cycle-footprint of the compilation is taken into account :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not receive "/home/test/*" as an argument; the shell expands the patter to the list of files that match, and your shell receives multiple arguments, one per matching file. Quoting the argument will work:

```
./simple.sh "/home/test/*"
```

Your change to using `DIR=/home/test/*` did what you expected because filename generation is not performed on the RHS of a variable assignment. When you left `$DIR` unquoted in the `for` loop, the pattern was expanded to the list of matching files.

Answer (score -2):

How about list the file manully instead of using *:

```
  #/usr/local/bin/bash
  for i in $(ls $1)
  do
      echo The current file is $i
  done
```

and type

```
 ./simple.sh /home/test/
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the file names in the directory contain whitespace.